# Error: List indices are supposed to be an integer but it is an integer

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop

I'm trying to create a while loop and have the index increase by 1 every time the loop runs.

I have `n` set to zero, which should tell python that this is an integer. However, when it gets to `if contact_list[n]['vid'] == '':`, it sees `n` as a string.

Here is the loop. Any help is greatly appreciated:

```
has_more = True

n = 0

while has_more:
    parameters = urllib.parse.urlencode(parameter_dict)
    get_url = get_all_contacts_url + parameters + property_params
    r = requests.get(url= get_url, headers = headers)
    response_dict = json.loads(r.text)
    has_more = response_dict['has-more']
    contact_list.append(response_dict['contacts'])
    parameter_dict['vidOffset']= response_dict['vid-offset']
    if len(contact_list) >= max_results:
        max_results += 100
    if contact_list[n]['vid'] == '':
        break
    contact_count += 1
print('loop finished')

list_length = len(contact_list) 
print("List Length:",list_length)

print("You've succesfully parsed through {} contact records and added them to a list".format(list_length))
```

Comment: It sees ['vid'] as string because it is an string.Could you print the output of      print(contact_list[n])

Comment: What's the error you are getting, if there's any

Comment: can you share the error that you are getting ?

Comment: Also I cannot see you incrementing the value of `n` anywhere here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 if 'vid' in contact_list:
    if contact_list[n] == '':
     break
```

Hope that helps!

Yes, and realized n is actually not being incremented, if that's the case just call 0 as the list index without having to assign n=0.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. In regards to the increment, count_count should be n.